# Wind Turbine Grid Tied Inverter Issues

Tags: voltage

After having overcome many initial issues with my TESUP Atlas 4 wind turbine I am now at the operational stage. The turbine is mast mounted. I have an average wind speed in excess 5.5 m/s. The three AC phases generated are changed to a single phase smoothed DC supply by a charge controller before being fed to the inverters. Then two Growatt 3 kW inverters, wired in parallel, initialising voltage 65 V, max 550 V, and a count-down period of 20 s, process the power generated back to the grid. At this stage I now realise that the inverters are starting up, standbying, starting up again continuously as the wind blows and then for a second or two drops below that necessary to maintain 65 V in the system. I believe that I need a device, possibly a current limiting transformer, to enable the inverter to stay live through the momentary wind lulls to enable instant generation most of the time. This would be in a similar way to a battery charging wind turbine which charges instantly when the charge voltage is met. TESP have "piggy-backed" inverters on the back of their battery charging setup and, though promising the world, have not thought this one through. They have not offered any support to date. I would very much like to make this work and would be very grateful for any advice that I receive to achieve this goal.

Comment: 1. If you're feeding back into the grid, why should you care if the system starts and stops? Is there a mechanical relay that might wear out? 2. How would current *limiting* provide power?? If you need a battery, add one. If you want a greater time between generation and standby to reduce the number of switch-overs, add a delay.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but the issues, to me, are more than those that you describe. In the real wind the wind blows steady for say 20 seconds allowing the inverter to almost come offf standby and then there is a lull for only one or two seconds before increasing again. This means, other than in a storm, the inverters are always off, on standy, on count-down but not actually generating. I need them to be always online with a standing supply of 65V plus so that any turbine generated voltage is instantly additional and the turbine becomes "loaded". At present, it is never loaded.

Comment: Do you really need 2 inverters in parallel?  That won't be helping.

Comment: "This means, other than in a storm, the inverters are always off." Then the issue is that you have insufficient wind in your location. It might work on a higher mast... or not. You would not get a noticeable reduction in the electric bill if generation were not continual,

Comment: The turbine is claimed by TESUP to be capable of generating 5kw maximum. It was sent originally with one 3kw inverter. I queried this on Trustpilot because the charge controller dump mode is disabled in inverter mode. TESUP, without further correspondence, sent me another inverter. Much wind turbine correspondence states that you require excess inverter capacity to absorb such outputs so this seemed quite a reasonable solution. I do not know what the turbine should generate because I cannot keep the inverter(s) online. I can use one or both in parallel by manual switching.

Comment: How big is the battery you operate this with / are contemplating?

Comment: This is a grid tied arrangement. There is no battery planned and I will only use one if necessary. TESUP sell it as a grid tied setup ready to go. When the wind "puffs up", 10 - 15m/sec, I am seeing in excess of 150v on the meter. Real wind is not steady, there is always a lull every 30seconds or so. I need something to take me through the momentary lulls so the inverter engages and stays engaged. Any further thoughts??

Comment: The Solar Edge inverter allows the setting of the wake-up to voltage to 0v. This would mean it will be drawing from grid when not operating. I am not sure if this option is possible for my Growatt inverters but it may be worth trying. I have no idea what, if any, issues it may cause if this setting is possible. Anyone, any ideas before I mess up the menus?